# Jetpack compose animate, If two state have same tartget value ,the animate not play

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

Use the jetpack compose anmiate api, If you want the animation to be in the same state as the initial state after execution ends ，the anmaite while not play!

I want the button can little shake and restore stability when I click it.

##### no use

```
    var change by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    val buttonRotate by animateFloatAsState(targetValue = if (change) 0f else 0f,
        animationSpec = keyframes {
            durationMillis = 600
            5f at 200
            -5f at 400
        })

 Button(modifier = modifier.width(200.dp)
        .height(50.dp)
        .rotate(buttonRotate)
        ,onClick = {
            change = !change
        })
```

##### useful

```
xxxx
    val buttonRotate by animateFloatAsState(targetValue = if (change) 0f else 0.001f, // different point
        animationSpec = keyframes {
            durationMillis = 600
            5f at 200
            -5f at 400
        })
xxxx
```

So, What is a better implementation method ? :)
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `Animatable` with `keyframeSpec` can impl this.

```
    val buttonRotate = remember {Animatable(0f) }

            LaunchedEffect(change) {
                buttonRotate.animateTo(0f, keyframes {
                    durationMillis = 600
                    5f at 200
                    -5f at 400
                })
            }
```